# Keycloak doesn't see PanacheRepositoryBase

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have created a keycloak-quarkus-server service which uses PanacheRepositoryBase to make database queries.

The project compiles without errors, but when I drag it to the ${keyсloak_home}/provider folder to run it as a provider, it throws an error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheRepositoryBase
```

I tried importing the quarkus panache lib in {keycloak_home}/lib/lib/deployment but that didn't change anything.

Comment: So you are trying to embed Keycloak into a Quarkus application?

Comment: yeap, that is right

Comment: That's not something that is really supported honestly...